# Spring Data QueryBuilder for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, query-builder

I have the following Document:

```
@Document(collection = "MyObject")
public class MyObject {

     ...
    private List<OtherObject> otherObjects;
}
```

My question is if it would be possible to make a query with **QueryBuilder** where I load a subSet of **otherObjects** without loading **MyObject**.
The background is that there can be a lot of objects in **otherObjects**, and I don't what to load all into the store.

Thanks a lot to obi1 for the hint. I am a beginner concerning Spring Data Query Builder. Currently, I have used Repositories like this:

```
public interface MyObjectRepository extends MongoRepository<MyObject, String> {

List<MyObject> findMyObjectByProperties(final String properties);
...
```

My question now would be how to use the query from Query Builder?

Answer (score -1):

sure, you can use the query builder to **select** the specific items you want returned.  Something like this:

```
// Using query builder
MyObject.
  find({ otherObjects: queryparam }).
  where('name.last').equals('Ghost').
  select('name occupation').
  exec(callback);
```

check out the example here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: Thanks for your response!, I would have another question - what I have to set for queryparam ? Thanks!

Comment: This response is for Javascript, not Java (Spring)